# Bind value to ComboBox from dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, data-binding, combobox

I have a list:

```
public SortedDictionary<string, string> ProjectDictionaryList { get; internal set; }
```

Now I want to bind the value to ComboBox:

```
ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectDictionaryList}" 
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Style="{StaticResource myCombo}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}"
```

But how to bind `ProjectDictionaryList.Value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` and bind `SelectedValue` to select a dictionary entry by its key:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectDictionaryList}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProject}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DisplayMemberPath=""` to display the Values in combobox  or
 if you don't want to do that `ProjectDictionaryList.Values` can be binded with the help of `{Binding Path=}`

Comment: it will be enough: DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=ProjectDictionaryList.Value}" ?

Comment: you have use `DisplayMemberPath="Value"`

Comment: and if u don't want to bind an entire object to ui you can do something like this too `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectDictionaryList.Value}"`

Comment: `Binding Path=ProjectDictionaryList.Value` makes no sense. A Dictionary has no Value property. You probably mean the `Values` collection, but then why use a Dictionary at all?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be `Values` and I just told there is an option like that too thought it might be helpful for other scenarios